# Does the timeBeginPeriod API affect the system clock?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a Win32 application, and there are some animiation UI in my application, to make the animiation more smooth, I called timeBeginPeriod to improve the time resolution, but I found the system clock will delay some seconds if my application is running very long time. Does the timeBeginPeriod affect the system clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I didn't know this but yes it can.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069(VS.85).aspx): "Use caution when calling timeBeginPeriod, as frequent calls can significantly affect the system clock, system power usage, and the scheduler."

Answer (score 2):

A call to `timeBeginPeriod` changes the systems interrupt period. As a consequence the update rate and the update increment of the system time changes accordingly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743614/1504523) answer proves a closer look at system time and timeBeginPeriod.

Comment: Very detailed and informative answer you linked to, thanks for pointing me to it