# C: Why is a fprintf(stdout,....) so slow?

Tags: c

I still often use console output to get ideas what's going on in my code.
I know this may be a bit old fashion, but I also use this to "pipe" stdout
into log files etc.

However, it turns out that the output to the console is slowed down for some 
reason. I was wondering if someone can explain why an fprintf() to a console
window appears to be sort of blocking.

What I've done/diagnosed so far:

1. I measured the time a simple 
   `fprintf(stdout,"quick fprintf\n");`
   It needs: 0.82ms (in average). This is considered by far too long since a `vsprintf_s(...)` writes the same output into a string in just a few microseconds. Therefore there must be some blocking specifically to the console.
2. In oder to escape from the blocking I have used `vsprintf_s(...)` to copy my output into a fifo alike data structure. The data structure is protected by a critical section object. A separate thread is then unqueing the data structure by putting the queued output to the console.
3. One further improvement I could obtain by the introduction of pipe services.
   The output of my program (supposed to end up in a console window) goes the following way:

   - A `vsprintf_s(...)` formats the output to simple strings.
   - The strings are queued into a fifo alike data structure, a linked list sructure for example. This data structure is protected by a critical section object.
   - A second thread dequeues the data structure by sending the output strings to a named pipe.
   - A second process reads the named pipe and puts the strings again into a fifo alike data
     structure. This is needed to keep the reading away from the blocking output to the console.
     The reading process is fast at reading the named pipe and monitors the fill level of the pipes buffer continuously.
   - A second thread in that second process finally dequeues the data structure by `fprintf(stdout,...)` to the console.

So I have two processes with at least two threads each, a named pipe between them, and fifo alike data structures on both sides of the pipe to avoid blocking in the event of pipe buffer full.

That is a lot of stuff to just make sure that console output is "non-blocking". But the result is
not too bad. My main program can write complex fprintf(stdout,...) within just a few microseconds.

Maybe I should have asked earlier: Is there some other (easier!) way to have nonblocking console output?

Comment: I suspect that it is the console which is slow. Terminal emulators tend to be slow (because their baud rate is part of their specifications). Did you just measure the time when redirecting *stdout* to some file? And you could output debugging information to some other `FILE` (and use `setvbuf` with a big buffer).

Comment: What operating system, libraries, compiler, are you working with?

Comment: The amount of time taken by `fprintf` isn't very interesting if you don't also know how much of that time is spent waiting for the output channel.

Comment: @Basile: Windows7, Visual C++. I did measure the total time between making the call to fprintf() and when it returned.

Comment: My guess: a pipe buffer is small (typically 1 4KB block) sending large amounts of output will cause the writer to block untill the reader has sucked sufficient data from the pipe. (on a single CPU machine this will cause reader and writer to ping-pong context-switch twice per block) Guess-2: if the program is multithreaded, the spinlocks inside malloc (inside snprintf) if any will hold all but one of the competing threads. In all cases: vmstat is your friend.

Comment: @ larsmans: Well the time is interesting to me in this context, because it holds up the execution of my code. As said: I can reach few microseconds with vsprintf(...) and I do observe almost a milisecond with fprintf(stdout,...). So most of the time would be spend waiting for the output channel.

Comment: @wildplasser: The pipe situation is clear to me. That's the reason why I have implemented fifos on either side of the pipe I'm using. And: Likely neither a memory problem nor a race condition. Tested on many hardware configutations: Single CPU and multi-core, same bahavior.

Comment: Not sure if it helps. But anyway, on Linux with line-buffered `stdout` it takes on average 0.000023904 sec per `fprintf(stdout,"quick fprintf\n");` for a run of 10000 calls.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: That's about what I do observe using the answer below.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: most Linux terminal emulators have been optimized for fast output, e.g: IIRC Konsole waits up to 50ms to get more input before displaying anything on screen.

Comment: @ninjalj Just for the record, I am using Emacs Shell mode, not a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the timing problem has to do with the fact that console is *line buffered* by default. This means that every time you write a `'\n'` character to it, your entire output buffer is sent to the console, which is a rather costly operation. This is the price that you pay for the line to appear in the output immediately.

You can change this default behavior by changing the buffering strategy to *full buffering*. The consequence is that the output will be sent to console in chunks that are equal to the size of your buffer, but individual operations will complete faster.

Make this call before you first write to console:

```
char buf[10000];
setvbuf(stdout, buf, _IOFBF, sizeof(buf));
```

The timing of individual writes should improve, but the output will not appear in the console immediately. This is not too useful for debugging, but the timing will improve. If you set up a thread that calls `fflush(stdout)` on regular time intervals, say, once every second, you should get a reasonable balance between the performance of individual writes and the delay between your program writing the output and the time when you can actually see it on the console.

Comment: Tested, confirmed, great answer. I hoped that there was some trick to speed this up

Comment: This should use `sizeof buf` instead of repeating the magic constant, of course. :)

Comment: @unwind Of course, you are right! It was an obvious omission on my part, you are welcome to edit my answers when you see me doing something as silly as this :) Thank you very much!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No output until either the buffer is full or the fflush(stdout) is performed. Thus the additional thread to perform the flush is mandatory.