# How does powercfg -energy detect the requested timer resolution

Tags: winapi, timer, system-information, powercfg

How does "powercfg -energy" command detect the requested timer resolution of each individual program running at the time?

I imagine one way would be injecting into each of running processes and inside that process calling **timeEndPeriod** for each increased resolution (values 1-15) in a loop over these resolutions and checking whether the **timeEndPeriod** call for a current resolution returns **TIMERR_NOCANDO** or **TIMERR_NOERROR** *(note: these return values are NOT correspondingly **false** and **true**)*. And if it returns **TIMERR_NOERROR** then concluding that the program is using that frequency, and then calling again **timeBeginPeriod**. But this method seems cumbersome. Moreover, it is a bit intrusive since it modifies the state of the process, and also assumes that powercfg is able to inject into all processes.

Is there instead some documented or undocumented system API that enables requesting that information for foreign processes? At least I would like to know how it works, even if that API remains a secret...

A related (but not the main) question is, how to get the maximum timer resolution (minimum interval) that is currently in effect in the system in case I am not interested in the requests of individual applications? I imagine that *maybe* **GetSystemTimeAdjustment()'s lpTimeIncrement** helps with that, but I am not too sure. Please confirm me or propose an alternate method.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the undocumented API of `NtQueryTimerResolution()`.

```
NTSTATUS NtQueryTimerResolution(OUT PULONGMinimumResolution, 
                                OUT LONGMaximumResolution, 
                                OUT PULONGActualResolution);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743614/1504523) for an example on how to use it. But it will only give the *ActualResolution* as configured by any process. It does not give the information which process has configured which multimedia timer resolution.

You wouldn't want to change each processes mutimedia setting to find out which process has aquired which resolution. It would only be needed to obtain information on which process has requested *ActualResolution*.

Note: powercfg /energy is only available from Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 upwards.